# Cannot use J2ME game.canvas

Tags: java, mobile, canvas, java-me

I'm doing some coding for a **J2ME** game and all the functions related to game. GameCanvas cannot be used and gives me errors, no error is shown while importing and it's been highlighted by "Unused Import".

```
package racex;

import java.lang.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.game.GameCanvas;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.game.LayerManager;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.game.TiledLayer;
import javax.microedition.media.Manager;



public class Sprite extends RaceX implements Runnable{

private Image image;
private int x, y,vx,vy,width, height;
private int numFrames, frame;
private boolean visibile;
private Image carImage;
private Sprite carSprite;
private TiledLayer background;
private final int ROAD_WIDTH=200;
private LayerManager Manager;
protected int areas[][]={{2,1,6,3},{3,4,4,5},{0,9,10,14}};


public Sprite(){
    super();
}




    public void start(){

    try{
carImage=Image.createImage("/car1x.png");
}catch(Exception ex){}

    Thread runner = new Thread((Runnable) this);
    runner.start();

        Manager = new LayerManager();
        Manager.append(background);


}

public void run(){
Graphics g = getGraphics();
carSprite.paint(g);

  while(true) { // infinite loop

    // based on the structure

    // first verify game state
    verifyGameState();

    // check user's input
    checkUserInput();

    // update screen
    updateGameScreen(getGraphics());

    // and sleep, this controls
    // how fast refresh is done
    try {
      Thread.currentThread().sleep(30);
    } catch(Exception e) {}

  }

}

private void verifyGameState() {
  // doesn't do anything yet
}

    private void checkUserInput(){
      int keyState = getKeyStates();
      calculateCarX(keyState);

    }

    private void updateGameScreen(Graphics g){
          System.out.println("Paint is WORKING");
  g.setColor(255,255,255);
  g.setStrokeStyle(Graphics.DOTTED);
  g.drawLine(getWidth()/2, 2, getWidth()/2, getHeight() -1); 
  buildGameScreen(g);
  g.setStrokeStyle(Graphics.SOLID);
  g.fillRect(0, 0, (getWidth()- ROAD_WIDTH)/2, getHeight());
  g.fillRect((getWidth() +ROAD_WIDTH)/2, 0, (getWidth() - ROAD_WIDTH)/2,getHeight());
  g.drawString("Score:", (getWidth()-ROAD_WIDTH)/2+1, 0, Graphics.TOP|Graphics.LEFT);
  System.out.println("Paint is Fully WORKING");
  //flushGraphics();
    }

public void buildGameScreen (Graphics g){
  System.out.println("Paint is WORKING");
  g.setColor(255,255,255);
  g.setStrokeStyle(Graphics.DOTTED);
  g.drawLine(getWidth()/2, 2, getWidth()/2, getHeight() -1); 

  g.setStrokeStyle(Graphics.SOLID);
  g.fillRect(0, 0, (getWidth()- ROAD_WIDTH)/2, getHeight());
  g.fillRect((getWidth() +ROAD_WIDTH)/2, 0, (getWidth() - ROAD_WIDTH)/2,getHeight());
  g.drawString("Score:", (getWidth()-ROAD_WIDTH)/2+1, 0, Graphics.TOP|Graphics.LEFT);
  System.out.println("Paint is Fully WORKING");

  background.paint(g);

}
private void calculateCarX(int keyState) {

  // determines which way to move and changes the
  // x coordinate accordingly
  if((keyState & LEFT_PRESSED) != 0) {
    carX -= dx;
  }
  else if((keyState & RIGHT_PRESSED) != 0) {
    carX += dx;
  }

}

// the couple image
private Image coupleImg;

// the couple image coordinates
private int carX;


// the distance to move in the x axis
private int dx = 1;

// the center of the screen
public final int CENTER_X = getWidth()/2;
public final int CENTER_Y = getHeight()/2;




public void paint (Graphics g){
        for (int i=0; i<areas.length; i++)
{
g.setClip(areas[i][0], areas[i][1], areas[i][2], areas[i][3]);
g.setClip(x, y, width, height);
g.drawImage(image, x-frame*width, y, Graphics.TOP | Graphics.LEFT);

//g.setClip(0, 0, Cache.width, height);
}
    } // Paint Brackets

public boolean collide(Sprite sprite){
if ((x+width) > sprite.getX() && x < sprite.getX() && (y+height)>sprite.getY() && y<sprite.getY()) 
    return true;
return false;
}


}
```

The following gives me errors:
- `LEFT_PRESSED`
- `RIGHT_PRESSED`
- `getGraphics()`
- `getKeyStates()`

Comment: Try import javax.microedition.lcdui.game.*;

Comment: I did and imported lcdui.game* and even less but same it shows me "Unused import"

Comment: Canvas and GameCanvas are abstract classes, meaning your own class has to extend Canvas or GameCanvas. I'm guessing you're not doing that, and that's why the import isn't used.

Comment: I have extended GameCanvas and that's works, thanks a lot :D